# How to have a div fill horizontal space to the left and right of a fixed width div

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div's: `divLeft`, `divCenter` and `divRight` and I want `divCenter` to be centered with a width of 1200px. The left and the right should have fluid width to fill up to the edge of the screen.

How can I do this?

Comment: so many topics on this on the net already https://www.google.com/?q=3+column+fluid+css

Comment: these are pure fluid. i need a static center

Comment: What happens when the screenWidth is less than `1200px`? Do the sidebars disappear, or do they have a minimum width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using javascript if these margins must contain content, if they are blank space, then use margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto.

for jQuery, something like this may work on page load/resize:

```
<div class="marginClass" id="divLeft"></div>
<div id="divCenter"></div>
<div class="marginClass" id="divRight"></div>
$(".marginClass").css("width", ( $(window).width() - $("#divCenter").width() / 2 ) + "px");
```

Good luck

Comment: @Wex, your solution is pretty clean. Thanks for the contribution, I now have a new tool in my arsenal.

Comment: -1 Something as trivial as this shouldn't require javascript, especially not an entire js library. OPs question wasn't even tagged [tag:javascript] or [tag:jquery]...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/BGU7V/

You might want to use this in conjunction with [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

```
.divCenter { 
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto; }
.divCenter p { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1200px; }​

.divLeft { float: left; width: 50%; }
.divLeft p { margin: 0 600px 0 0; }

.divRight { float: right; width: 50%; }
.divRight p { margin: 0 0 0 600px; }
```

Comment: I need to spend some time going through this CSS; at first glance however, looks clever! Nice.

Comment: @Shango - Think of it like this: each sidebar takes up 50% of the page. You add an inner element to each sidebar which pushes the content of the sidebars 600px away from the middle of the page, creating a 1200px gap in the middle of the page for the center div. Absolute positioning makes it so the it doesn't push the floated sidebars down.

Comment: Makes sense. Flexbox should simplify layouts like this, even though CSS puzzles are fun :D

Comment: This is a great solution, and should probably be used before mine.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I can think of is using `calc()` function:

```
.center,
.side {
  float: left;
}

.center {
  width: 1200px;
}

.side {
  width: -webkit-calc((100% - 1200px) / 2));
  width: calc((100% - 1200px) / 2));
}​
```